# Group Tenure of customers in the sequence in R?

Tags: r, grouping

I'm trying to Group Tenure of customers in the sequence ‘seq(3,7.5,by=1.5)’)
How to do this?
Please Help!!

Answer (score 1):

We can use the `rep` with `length.out`

```
customerlength <- 20
rep(seq(3,7.5,by=1.5), length.out=20)
```